# Why do some airlines stop selling tickets 3 hours before the flight departure?

Tags: tickets, airlines

I've encountered some airline that stops selling tickets 3 hours before the flight departure on their website, and don't sell tickets in person at the airport. Why do some airlines stop selling tickets 3 hours before the flight departure?

The front desk agents at the airport didn't know the answer when I asked them.

Comment: Can you say which airline?

Comment: As many airports have 'be there two or three hours in advance' rules for many flights, I would be surprised if they sell tickets right to the cut off time for checking in.

Comment: @Willeke many do, I've bought tickets right before the check-in counter closes.

Comment: @ajd some low-cost airline

Comment: At some point the paperwork has to get started, including how much belly cargo etc can be taken, how many standby passengers have a chance, upgrades etc etc etc.

Comment: Selling in-person requires infrastructure and personnel that low-cost carriers don't want to spend money on. I don't know if there ever was a time where people would normally just come to the airport and buy a ticket in person for the next flight, but nowadays everything is online and in-person sales are a relic of the past.

Comment: @littleadv thanks, agreed for the in-person overhead. Sometimes in case of emergency or missed fight one has to buy a ticket at the counter at the last minute. Why do some airlines stop selling tickets 3 hours before the flight departure?

Comment: @Moo your arguments would also apply to buying at the counter. But many airlines allow buying at the counter at the least minutes. Eg standby is till check-in closes typically, so that's not an issue

Comment: @Moo's argument is very valid. Full-cost airlines can afford being occasionally late on departure, dealing with overbooking, or bear the extra costs of better customer experience. Low-cost airlines, which you've mentioned you're talking about, cannot.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Then your best answer is going to be “ask the airline why they do X, when X is not an industry standard activity”.  Have you done that?  You are asking a generic question while simultaneously saying that theres no generic answer.

Comment: @Moo there could be a generic answer that we're missing. Also I don't know about the common practice about last-minute online purchases.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You've already dismissed the generic answers.  Go ask the airline.  Until you’ve done that, I think the downvotes here are earned.

Comment: @Moo the front desk had no clue when I asked. Front facing agents aren't always the most knowledgeable.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt plenty of other aspects of the airline you an ask - the PR and marketing department may have a slow enough day to elicit a decent answer from, for example.  Reach out on social media etc etc.

Comment: @Moo  I was thinking of asking it on a   question and answer site for road warriors and seasoned travelers.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the issue with that is that you are, again, not asking about anything that has a generic answer, you are wanting company-specific information - the only authoritative place for that is the company itself.  Anything else is speculation - you might get someone who claims to be "in the know", but this is just an appeal to authority fallacy where the "authority" is unproven.

Comment: @Moo a claim for some random airline employee isn't either always guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt a claim issued through official channels carries hugely more weight than "Bob - GitHub Stop Helping ICE I SUPPORT MONICA!!!" on some StackExchange site...

Comment: @Moo Are you sure? He's supporting Monica. Anyway, yes, I'll add any info I can find. Took me 9h last time I called a customer service from an airline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comments: 1)  it is expensive for the airline to sell tickets at the airport 2) some paperwork has to be done a fair amount of time before the flight departs.

---

> - At some point the paperwork has to get started, including how much belly cargo etc can be taken, how many standby passengers have a chance, upgrades etc [Moo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/29788/moo) [10 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174665/why-do-some-airlines-stop-selling-tickets-3-hours-before-the-flight-departure#comment436983_174665)
> - Selling in-person requires infrastructure and personnel that low-cost carriers don't want to spend money on. [littleadv](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1295/littleadv)  [5 hours ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174665/why-do-some-airlines-stop-selling-tickets-3-hours-before-the-flight-departure#comment436997_174665)